# What does mpn_invert_3by2 in mini-gmp do?

Tags: gmp

I really wonder the answer to this question. and I used python to calculate:

```
def inv(a):
    return ((1 << 96) - 1) // (a << 32)
```

Why is python's result different from `mpn_invert_limb`'s?

```
/* The 3/2 inverse is defined as

     m = floor( (B^3-1) / (B u1 + u0)) - B
*/
B should be 2^32
```

And what is the use of mpn invert_limb?

Python code:

```
def inv(a):
    return ((1 << 96) - 1) // (a << 32)


a = 165536
b = inv(a)
print(b & (2 ** 32 - 1))
```

C code:

```
int main()
{
    mp_limb_t a = 16636;
    mp_limb_t b;
    b = mpn_invert_limb(a);
    printf("a = %u, b = %u\n", a, b);
    printf("a = %X, b = %X\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Python output:

```
3522819686
```

C output:

```
a = 165536, b = 3165475657
a = 286A0, b = BCAD5349
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling mpn_invert_limb only makes sense when your input is full-sized (has its high bit set).  If the input isn't full sized then the quotient would be too big to fit in a single limb whereas in the full sized case its only 1 bit too big hence the subtraction of B in the definition.

I actually can't even run with your input of 16636, I get a division by 0 because this isn't even half a limb.  Anyway, if I replace that value by `a<<17` then I get a match between your Python and C.  This shifting to make the top bit be set is what mini-gmp does in its usage of the function.